# Node fetching failed, but one also works

Tags: node.js, fetch, bots, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot with `discord.js` and `node.js`. I am trying to make two commands, a `purr` command and a `woof` command. I am using [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to get images from the web and post them to discord. Here is my code:

```
else if (command === 'purr') {
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow').then(response => response.json());
    const { file } = await fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow').then(response => response.json());
    const catEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#fbfb76')
        .setTitle('Purr...')
        .setImage(file)
        .setFooter('Over 1000 free cat pics thanks to aws.random.cat :)');
    message.channel.send(catEmbed);
}
else if (command === 'woof') {
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(response => response.json());
    const { file } = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(response => response.json());
    message.channel.send(file);
}
```

The `purr` command works. The woof command...well, not really. It outputs this error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

Indicating that it failed to fetch from `dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random`. Since it worked for the `purr` command, but not the `woof` command, could somebody tell me the problem and suggest how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this rn, but I'd say you need to send it like `send({ file })` and not just plain send the while when it expects a string

Comment: The only problem is that it outputs the same error i got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `https://aws.random.cat/meow` returns a `file` variable. However, `https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random` returns a `message` variable. use this instead:

```js
const { message } = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(response => response.json());
```

Comment: lol that's completely my fault. Sorry, I haven't had my coffee yet today haha. Check the edited answer.

Comment: There's a problem; I've already declared message in the upper scope, so do I do something like ```const { message1 } ......```?

Comment: You could just do `const res = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then(response => response.json());` and then `res.message` to get the message.

Comment: Glad I could help :) make sure to [mark my answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work. It says 'cannot read 'message' of null'.